# Linq To Entities query is extremely slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, indexing

I'm using ASP.NET 4.5, Entity Framework 5.0 & LINQ with SQL Server 2012.

This is a web based application for a real estate website. The table this query is pulling data from has roughly 200 columns and about 3.2 million rows.

When I use EF to get some data, it generates the following query:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Filter1].[ListingID] AS [ListingID], 
[Filter1].[Address] AS [Address], 
[Filter1].[Beds] AS [Beds], 
[Filter1].[BathsFull] AS [BathsFull], 
[Filter1].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice], 
[Filter1].[RemarksPublic] AS [RemarksPublic], 
[Filter1].[MLSBoardID] AS [MLSBoardID], 
[Filter1].[PropertyTypeID] AS [PropertyTypeID], 
[Filter1].[sysid] AS [sysid], 
[Filter1].[ListAgentID] AS [ListAgentID], 
[Filter1].[LastUpdateDate] AS [LastUpdateDate], 
[Filter1].[ShowAddressOnlineYN] AS [ShowAddressOnlineYN], 
[Filter1].[City] AS [City], 
[Filter1].[State] AS [State], 
[Filter1].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode], 
[Filter1].[MLSNumber] AS [MLSNumber], 
[Filter1].[County] AS [County], 
[Filter1].[LeasePrice] AS [LeasePrice]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[ListingID] AS [ListingID], [Extent1].[MLSBoardID] AS [MLSBoardID], [Extent1].[PropertyTypeID] AS [PropertyTypeID], [Extent1].[sysid] AS [sysid], [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address], [Extent1].[BathsFull] AS [BathsFull], [Extent1].[Beds] AS [Beds], [Extent1].[City] AS [City], [Extent1].[County] AS [County], [Extent1].[LastUpdateDate] AS [LastUpdateDate], [Extent1].[LeasePrice] AS [LeasePrice], [Extent1].[ListAgentID] AS [ListAgentID], [Extent1].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice], [Extent1].[MLSNumber] AS [MLSNumber], [Extent1].[RemarksPublic] AS [RemarksPublic], [Extent1].[ShowAddressOnlineYN] AS [ShowAddressOnlineYN], [Extent1].[State] AS [State], [Extent1].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (Case When [Extent1].[ListAgentID] IN ('##########') Then 0 Else 1 End), ListPrice DESC, LeasePrice DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Listings] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1009 = [Extent1].[PropertyTypeID]
)  AS [Filter1]
WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY (Case When [Filter1].[ListAgentID] IN ('##########') Then 0 Else 1 End), ListPrice DESC, LeasePrice DESC
```

This query takes an estimated 45-50 seconds to execute and return the 2 rows. I can see from the Execution Plan, that majority of cost is in "Sort" and "Sort (Top N Sort)". These account for 79% cost of the entire query.

I manually re-write the above query to this:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[ListingID], 
[Address], 
[Beds], 
[BathsFull], 
[ListPrice], 
[RemarksPublic], 
[MLSBoardID], 
[PropertyTypeID], 
[sysid], 
[ListAgentID], 
[LastUpdateDate], 
[ShowAddressOnlineYN], 
[City], 
[State], 
[ZipCode], 
[MLSNumber], 
[County], 
[LeasePrice]
FROM  dbo.Listings
WHERE 1009 = [PropertyTypeID]
ORDER BY (Case When [ListAgentID] IN ('##########') Then 0 Else 1 End), ListPrice DESC, LeasePrice DESC
```

My query returns the exact same results as the one before but it takes less than 1 second to run (the "Sort (Top N Sort)" taking 91% of cost). Both queries use the same index on the "Index Seek" of their execution plans.

How can I make the first query run faster? I've tried all kinds of things with indexes but can't seem to make it execute at the speed of the 2nd query that I wrote.

Any and all help is appreciated. If you need more details, just let me know.

Comment: What does your LINQ query look like?

Comment: you put an index on `PropertyTypeID` ?

Comment: off topic comment: you can execute your query in EF `context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Listing>("SELECT ... WHERE PropertyTypeID = {0} ...", 1009).ToList();` and this will be faster. Problem can be in case of model change. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee358758%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: You'll need to change the LINQ expression to try and get your desired  query. The `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` won't be able to use an index (except if you were to create a computed column with that expression). The time differences are a bit odd though as the `TOP N` sort still needs to scan all qualifying rows. Maybe the full sort  is spilling to disc. In SQL Server 2012 this shows up in the actual execution plan in previous versions you can trace sort warnings in Profiler to see if this is the case.

Comment: try 2 separate queries to avoid case in Order by.  Does SQL sever have enough memory allocated ?  The index has a better chance of being in memory then. BTW Is row_number in the index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your comments.

@Rowland - It is difficult to show the LINQ query because it is fully dynamic and integrated into a quite complex system where the query is generated by several factors.

@meda - Yes, there is an index that has the field "PropertyTypeID" as one of it's fields. Is there a problem with that?

@Martin - You're right.

The issue had something to do with the way the order by was being generated. I tweaked that method and this is the resulting SQL query that LINQ to EF generated to pull the same results:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Project1].[ListingID] AS [ListingID], 
[Project1].[Address] AS [Address], 
[Project1].[Beds] AS [Beds], 
[Project1].[BathsFull] AS [BathsFull], 
[Project1].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice], 
[Project1].[RemarksPublic] AS [RemarksPublic], 
[Project1].[MLSBoardID] AS [MLSBoardID], 
[Project1].[PropertyTypeID] AS [PropertyTypeID], 
[Project1].[sysid] AS [sysid], 
[Project1].[ListAgentID] AS [ListAgentID], 
[Project1].[LastUpdateDate] AS [LastUpdateDate], 
[Project1].[ShowAddressOnlineYN] AS [ShowAddressOnlineYN], 
[Project1].[City] AS [City], 
[Project1].[State] AS [State], 
[Project1].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode], 
[Project1].[MLSNumber] AS [MLSNumber], 
[Project1].[County] AS [County], 
[Project1].[LeasePrice] AS [LeasePrice]
FROM ( SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ListAgentID] IN ('XXXXXXXXX')) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[ListingID] AS [ListingID], 
    [Extent1].[MLSBoardID] AS [MLSBoardID], 
    [Extent1].[PropertyTypeID] AS [PropertyTypeID], 
    [Extent1].[sysid] AS [sysid], 
    [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address], 
    [Extent1].[BathsFull] AS [BathsFull], 
    [Extent1].[Beds] AS [Beds], 
    [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Extent1].[County] AS [County], 
    [Extent1].[LastUpdateDate] AS [LastUpdateDate], 
    [Extent1].[LeasePrice] AS [LeasePrice], 
    [Extent1].[ListAgentID] AS [ListAgentID], 
    [Extent1].[ListPrice] AS [ListPrice], 
    [Extent1].[MLSNumber] AS [MLSNumber], 
    [Extent1].[RemarksPublic] AS [RemarksPublic], 
    [Extent1].[ShowAddressOnlineYN] AS [ShowAddressOnlineYN], 
    [Extent1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Extent1].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode]
    FROM [dbo].[Listings] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1009 = [Extent1].[PropertyTypeID]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC, [Project1].[ListPrice] DESC, [Project1].[LeasePrice] DESC
```

This takes less than a second to execute as it should. Thanks everyone for your input.